# JQuery UI Dialog Positioning Center of Parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, user-interface, dialog, position

I have a functioning snippet as follows...

```
function LoadTheDialog($url) {
  $dialog = $('<div></div>');
  $dialog.html('<iframe id="theDialog" src="' + $url + '"  width="530px" height="600px" style="border: 0px;"></iframe>');
  $dialog.dialog({ width: 555, modal: true, resizable: false, draggable: false, 
    open: function (type, data) { $($dialog).parent().appendTo("body"); }
  }).dialog('widget').position({ my: "center", at: "center", of: window, collision: "none" }); 
};
```

no matter what I have tried thus far, the dialog always shows up at top left of the browser...

Am I missing something obvious?

I would also like to bag the static width & height and have it auto size to the size of the loaded remote content but those options do not seem to work as anticipated either...

thanks in advance.

Comment: must be something on your css.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

ok solved.

You need to call you dialog like this:

```
window.parent.jQuery(>>the html or variable of your dialog<<).dialog({ >>the options<<  });
```

so that way it gets appended to the parent document and gets back to normal positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to also set the height in the jQuery UIDialog. 
I fixed the problem by setting the height and width of the dialog to the same of the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955595/jquery-ui-dialog-inside-of-an-iframe):

```
position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top}
```