# JQuery UI Dialog inside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-dialog

I'm developing a sp2013 app, which means it's using iframes. Specifically, it's a very large iframe which takes up most of the screen. At many points, I'm opening up jquery ui dialog windows. They are set to appear in the middle of the viewport, which is great, except it's showing up in the middle of the iframe, rather than the middle of the visible screen.

Is there a way I can tell jquery ui to look at window.top's scroll properties, instead of the iframes?

Edit: The iframe and the parent are on the same domain, so cross-domain issues aren't a problem.

Comment: could you try and put this in the head of the page that's loaded in the iframe? `<base target="_parent" />`

Comment: Try the jQuery postMessage plugin, thats a cross-frame communication tool, and you transfer variables and methods with that. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: @Jules That won't do anything to a jQuery dialog.

Comment: @Mooseman If jQuery UI is implemented correctly, which it is most of the time, it could look at the page base and use it as the reference-windows to display a dialog. I'm not going to bother trying this myself, but I really think it's worth a shot

Comment: @Jules: that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Too bad, would have been an awesome solution if it did though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution. When declaring my dialog, I did the following:

```
$("selector").dialog({
    position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top}
});
```

Comment: This fails on cross-domain, **Error: Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'** in jquery.min.js.

Comment: Correct. I added that they were the same domain in my question. I'm not sure of a solution that would work cross-domain.

Comment: Thanks @Colin, I have posted a [new question on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921363/jquery-ui-dialog-in-a-cross-domain-iframe?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">Hello, world!</div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert('Window size: '+window.innerWidth);
var dialogWidth = 500;
var dialogHeight = 200;
var dialogX = (window.innerWidth - dialogWidth)/2;
var dialogY = (window.innerHeight - dialogHeight)/2;
$("#dialog").dialog({ position: [dialogX,dialogY], width: dialogWidth, height: dialogHeight }, 500);
alert('Dialog position: '+$("#dialog").dialog( "option", "position" ));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vjsa/3/
Runs inside iframe. Centered horizontally and vertically. If the centered position of the window would fall outside of the iframe, it will be moved to the edge of the iframe. Alert messages added to show window width and dialog position.

Comment: Hmm. I think this is just redoing what jquery ui already does. But it did lead me to the correct answer.

Comment: My answer lets you do a little more than `position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top}` does. Use what works for you.

Comment: Yours also would still be in the center of the iframe, though. It doesn't actually answer the question.