# JQuery3 Dialog inside of an iframe position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, modal-dialog, position

I'm trying to open a dialog inside an iframe.
When I set position as:

```
   position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window }
```

It refers to the window of the iframe.
And that requires me to scroll when the iframe is long.
I tryed using :

```
  position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window.top}
```

but I got this error:

```
jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
    at La (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Ma (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.css (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.get (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.css (jquery.min.js:3)
    at jquery.min.js:4
    at S (jquery.min.js:3)
    at jQuery.fn.init.r.fn.<computed> [as outerWidth] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at d (jquery-ui.custom.min.js:formatted:614)
    at jQuery.fn.init.e.fn.position (jquery-ui.custom.min.js:formatted:666)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please Review https://api.jqueryui.com/position/ *Type: Selector or Element or jQuery or Event* `window.top` is not a Selector, Element, Object, or Event.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for answering! window.top I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15956081

Comment: Consider the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the following:

```
position: { my: 'center', at: 'top', of: window }
```

Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/position/

The `at` portion can use horizontal and vertical elements.

> Defines which position on the target element to align the positioned element against: "horizontal vertical" alignment. See the `my` option for full details on possible values. Percentage offsets are relative to the target element.

When review the `my` definition, it says:

> Defines which position on the element being positioned to align with the target element: "horizontal vertical" alignment. A single value such as `"right"` will be normalized to `"right center"`, `"top"` will be normalized to `"center top"` (following CSS convention). Acceptable horizontal values: `"left"`, `"center"`, `"right"`. Acceptable vertical values: `"top"`, `"center"`, `"bottom"`. Example: `"left top"` or `"center center"`. Each dimension can also contain offsets, in pixels or percent, e.g., `"right+10 top-25%"`. Percentage offsets are relative to the element being positioned.