# Center jquery ui dialog inside iframe where click event happened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having trouble opening a dialog right where a click event happened inside an iframe.  I have commented code below that just doesnt work correctly on click.

```
var def = {
                    autoOpen: false,
                    bgiframe: true,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 'auto',
                    modal: true,
                    dialogClass: 'loader-container',
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    position: 'center',
                    open: function(event, ui) {
                        $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();

                        if (values.options.isWidget) {
                            //$(this).dialog('option', 'position', { my: "center", at: "center", of: event });
                        }
                    },
                    close: function(event, ui) {

                    }
                };

                $(element).dialog(def);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery UI Dialog Positioning Center of Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960090/jquery-ui-dialog-positioning-center-of-parent)